# Php Session Resets on SSL

Tags: php, linux, session-state

This is a variant of a common php problem that seems to defy solution (and common sense): when a user switches between http and https on my site, php dumps the contents of the session. This would be bad enough, except for the fact that the site works fine when I run it under the domain test.mysite.com. The problem only shows up when I run it under www.mydomain.com, and only on our new server. The code worked just fine on my old machine!

Both servers are running CentOS, with the troublesome one on Rackspace CloudServer.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Just to make something clearer: the session actually gets *cleared* when going to a secure page. I can't go back to an unsecured page to view the original contents of the session, even though the session id's haven't changed.

Comment: Is the SSL version actually running on the same node?  It is possible to split them.

Comment: "the session actually gets cleared" - I find that **very** unlikely - are you sure you've not just lost the session id or did you really check the serialized data file / record.

Comment: "I find that very unlikely" - so do I, hence my preamble about defying common sense. I had a look at the data the browser is sending through fiddler - the session ids are indeed the same; the browser (or php) doesn't create a new session when navigating to a secure page. I'm not sure what's getting serialized, but whatever the case, the session information is not available to me when returning to the unsecured page.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've fallen victim to the curse of the dreaded php.ini file. Some cookie parameters are getting set differently.

I would ensure that the php.ini files in development and production are EXACTLY the same, you are running the same version of PHP, ideally the same build.

---

EDIT: ok, so it's not necessarily a difference in php.ini.

Have a look at the domain you're using for your cookies. If you set a cookie without explicitly setting the domain, it is the current domain only.

If this is www.example.com, users who visit http://example.com/ then are redirected to https://www.example.com/ WILL LOSE THEIR COOKIES.

Why? Because the cookie is being set for the exact domain, and won't be sent by the browser to a different host name.

The same is true if you run the site on multiple names. Be sure that you only run the site on *exactly one name*. If a user arrives on any other name, redirect them with a permanent redirect to the One True Name, before setting any cookies.

Comment: They are both on the same machine running the same version of php!

Comment: Do you know what settings I should look out for?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have the routing set up such that the domain is always exactly the same. The really puzzling thing about this is not that the session information doesn't propagate to the secured pages, but that the session information actually gets **cleared** when navigating to a secure page. I can't go back to the unsecured page to see the session information.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try setting the `secure` flag to false using this function?

```
<?php
    session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".mysite.com",false,true);
?>
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I should be a little clearer: the session *clears* when going to the secure page. If I hit the back button on the browser, the session will be empty.